# Adding namespaces to ASP.NET MVC 3 views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, namespaces

I tried adding namespaces to `configuration/system.web/pages/namespaces` in the web.config of my ASP.NET MVC 3 application so I could use classes in those namespaces in my views without needing a @using, however this has no effect. How can I add namespaces to my views?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

MVC razor has a different area for namespaces.

Look in the second web.config, the one in your Views folder and add namespaces this way.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Heh, didn't even notice there was a web.config there. Works 100%, thanks and +1. Will accept in a few minutes.

Comment: Note, the below answer of closing and re-opening the view was also required before Visual Studio would stop giving me an error after adding the Resource folder to the namespace and re-building the solution.

Comment: great answer, you should remove the extra ';' <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;"/> though. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure why it's so flaky, but chances are that it *is* actually working, but Visual Studio doesn't recognize it until you close and re-open the view you're in.  Also make sure you're in the web.config that's located in the Views directory.

Comment: Tried that, no dice. ;) I made sure to try uploading and executing the page before posting, and it failed to compile the view.

Comment: So you're modifying the web.config at the root of the Views directory like @DisplacedGuy recommended? I think that should take care of it.  Also make sure you're in the `system.web.webPages.razor` hierarchy if that's the view engine you're using.

Comment: Yeah my original problem was that I was using `configuration/system.web/pages/namespaces` and not `system.web.webPages.razor` as @DisplacedGuy suggested.

Comment: After two hours without making it work, I realized your post, closed the views, reopened and it worked... thanks for your observations ataddeini

Answer (score 1):

I used this method to include Resource files into my views but Razor didn't want to pick up my classes. After some hair-pulling I realized I didn't change the Access Modifier on the `Resources.resx` file to public (it's created as Internal by default). Once I changed it & recompiled, I could access my resources from all views.

Rookie mistake, hate to see it happen, but hopefully it'll save someone some pain.